# How to make better movement in Java JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

So I have been working on this game and I cant get the movement to be smooth. When I Release one key and I have another key pressed (like at first both W and S are pressed and then I released W) it stops. I have tried many different methods and none work. Does anyone have any idea on how I could fix this. Thanks.

Here is the code...

```
public void getKeyInputs() {
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                player.moveCharUp();
            }
            else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                player.moveCharDown();
            }

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                player.moveCharRight();
            }
            else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                player.moveCharLeft();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            player.stationaryX();
            player.stationaryY();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: A KeyEvent is only generated for one KeyStroke at a time. If you want to handle multiple keys you need to manually track each key as it is pressed/released. Check out [Motion Using the KeyBoard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). The `KeyboardAnimation` example show one way to do this.

Comment: @camickr can I use multiple keylisteners to do this

Comment: The link gives a recommendation NOT to use ANY KeyListeners. Two KeyListeners will do nothing. The event will still only be generated for the last key pressed/released.